# Azure Devops Yaml pipeline variable(eg Process.Clean) scopped to a stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

We need to run Selenium Grid on environment agent. To Start Selenium Grid we start PowerShell script StartSeleniumGrid.ps1. That powershell file starts java process which is Selenium Hub. By default after task is executed all processes started by a task got killed by Agent. In classic pipelines we have had that a stage had `Process.Clean` set to false. It worked perfectly for us we have had a Selenium Grid starting fine. We need to start it in the morning and leave it running and shutdow in the evening. Now we need same thing in yaml pipeline.
I have checked in classic pipeline this setting is adding environment variable named "PROCESS_CLEAN" with a value "false".

I have specified variable named "Process_Clean", which created same environment variable "PROCESS_CLEAN" with a value "false". But this did not help. The java process got killed.

We need to make it working on windows. Unfortunately k8s & some other container solutions are out of the consideration for now.

Comment: What do you mean by "specify scope as a task name"? What are you trying to do? What is the scenario you are trying to implement, and why are you trying to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Devops Yaml pipeline variable(eg Process.Clean) scopped to a stage

You could try to set the variable `Process.Clean` to `false` instead of `Process_Clean` in the Variables for our YAML pipeline.

[image]

The test result with `Process.Clean` to `false`:

[image]

And the test result with `Process.Clean` to `true`:

[image]

So, set `process.clean` to `false` in the variables of the YAML pipeline will stop the "finalize job" step from killing all processes.